# How to convert Base64 to Image Object in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, base64, blob

I am trying to upload an image in **Ionic 3** but I got image in `Base64`, so I want to convert it into Image file Object.

How do I convert it?

Here is my component code

```
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.profilePhoto['profile_photo'] = base64Image;
      let formData = new FormData();

      let blob: Blob = this.utilService.convertBase64ToImage(base64Image);
      let file = new File([blob], this.utilService.newGuid() + '.jpg', { type: 'image/jpeg' });
      let newFileObj = this.utilService.convertFileObject(file);

      formData.append('profile_photo', newFileObj);
      this.updatePhoto(formData);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

> with this code i did't get **image object like web**, so how to convert this base64 into image object like Web

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?  If you converted your base64 to a `Blob` correctly, you should be able to put the blob directly into the `FormData` (no need to convert to a `File`).  Then upload to your API.

```
let blob: Blob = this.utilService.convertBase64ToImage(base64Image);
await this.uploadImage(blob);

uploadImage(imageBlob: Blob, fileName = "imageUpload.png") {

  let p = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', imageBlob, fileName);

    let params = new HttpParams();

    this.httpClient.post('http://YOUR_API_HERE', formData,        
      {
        responseType: 'text', //Empty response is expected, no JSON
      })
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // We don't care what we get back here...
          resolve();
        },
        error => {
          //We didn't get data back
          console.log("Error submitting image upload")
          let e = new Error("Error uploading an image");
          reject(e);
        });
  });

  return p;
}
```